# How to correctly format PIL.Image.frombytes using external usb camera data

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I've had hard time to read data I received from a USB camera and display it correctly. I succeeded, but I worry that I'm doing something wrong because my solution is hacky.

The usb camera I'm using ([ui-1640le](https://en.ids-imaging.com/store/ui-1640le.html)) returns a byte array that I want to display.
I used `PIL.Image.frombytes("RGB", (imageWidth, imageHeight), image_bytes)`
But the image I got was in black and white and repeated itself:
[Image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbmuL.png)

I tried using the `"L"` format. `PIL.Image.frombytes("L", (imageWidth, imageHeight), image_bytes)` to see what will happen and I got: [this B&W image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZbhJ.png). Except for being B&W the image looked correct and the function only read third of the data.

So I reverse engineered the data with this code:

```
# Reorder the bytes structure
x=[]
for i in range(width*height):
    x += [img[i],img[i+width*height],img[i+2*width*height]]
image_bytes = bytes(x)


# Create a PIL Image
im = PIL.Image.frombytes("RGB", (imageWidth, imageHeight), image_bytes)

# Not sure why the image is flipped, but this fixes it
im.rotate(-90).transpose(PIL.Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT).show()
```

After that I finally get the picture as it should be: [final image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEOTB.png)

Does this solution make sense to read camera input, am I doing something wrong? Is there a more straight forward approach I'm missing?

Comment: Please show the code where you set up the camera and acquire the image. It looks like the data is in planar format, i.e. interleaved by plane rather than interleaved by pixel, though not sure why there are 9 copies.

Comment: I acquire the image data through intermediator code I don't have access to e.g. `client.SendMessage(CAM_FRAME_MSG_CODE)`. It might be that the issue is there but I think it's just sends the data as it gets it. Mostly, I want to verify I'm not missing an obvious better way to use .frombytes() since I'm new to working with this library.
Thanks for your response.

Comment: Can you print `type(img)`, and `img.shape` and `img.dtype` before you do the re-ordering please?

Comment: type(img) returns: bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst your method of packing the planar-interleaved data into pixel-interleaved data will work, you will almost certainly find the Numpy method is many tens of times faster.

First, I'll synthesise your input data:

```
import numpy as np

# Height, width and bytes per image channel
h,w = 100,256
bpc = h * w

# Now make the first (red) plane = 255, the second (green) plane = 127 and the final (blue) plane = 0
img = bytes(b"\xff"*bpc) + bytes(b"\x7f"*bpc) + bytes(b"\x00"*bpc)
```

So, `img` should now be a representative 100x256 orange image such as you might acquire. I would then interleave the data and make a PIL Image like this with Numpy:

```
from PIL import Image

# Make a Numpy array for each channel's pixels
R = np.frombuffer(img, dtype=np.uint8, count=bpc).reshape((h,w))  
G = np.frombuffer(img, dtype=np.uint8, count=bpc, offset=bpc).reshape((h,w))  
B = np.frombuffer(img, dtype=np.uint8, count=bpc, offset=2*bpc).reshape((h,w))

# Interleave the pixels from RRRRRRGGGGGGBBBBBB to RGBRGBRGBRGBRGB
RGB = np.dstack((R,G,B))

# Make PIL Image from Numpy array
pImage = Image.fromarray(RGB)
```

That takes 30 microseconds on my machine, versus 7 milliseconds with `for` loops, so some 230x faster.

[image]

**Keywords**: Python, Numpy, PIL, image processing, interleave, interleaved, de-interleave, planar, by pixel, by plane, pack, unpack.