# How to display a byte array image on a QLabel?

Tags: python, image-processing, pyqt5

I read a byte array of size: height*width*3 (3=RGB) that represents an image. This is raw data that I receive from a USB camera.

I was able to display and save it using PIL [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59745279/how-to-correctly-format-pil-image-frombytes-using-external-usb-camera-data). Now I'm trying to display it on a PyQt5 window.

I have tried using `QLabel.setPixmap()` but it seems I can not create a valid pixel map.

Failed attempt reading the byte array:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QByteArray
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel

    self.camLabel = QLabel()
    pixmap = QPixmap()
    loaded = pixmap.loadFromData(QByteArray(img)) # img is a byte array of size: h*w*3
    self.imgLabel.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

in this example `loaded` returns `False` so I know `imgLabel.setPixmap` will not work, but I don't know how to debug further to find out why the loading has failed.

A second failed attempt trying to use PIL library:

```
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageQt

    pImage = PIL.Image.fromarray(RGB) # RGB is a numpy array of the data in img
    qtImage = PIL.ImageQt.ImageQt(pImage)
    pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(qtImage)
    self.imgLabel.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

In this example the application crashes when I'm running: `self.imgLabel.setPixmap(pixmap)`, so again, I'm not sure how to debug further.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: show img(bytes) example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a `QPixmap` from the numpy array you could create an `QImage` first and use that to create the `QPixmap`. For example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
import numpy as np

# generate np array of (r, g, b) triplets with dtype uint8
height = width = 255
RGBarray = np.array([[r % 256, c % 256, -c % 256] for r in range(height) for c in range(width)], dtype=np.uint8)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
# create QImage from numpy array
image = QtGui.QImage(bytes(RGBarray), width, height, 3*width, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(image)

label.setPixmap(pixmap)
label.show()
app.exec()
```

[image: screenshot of pixmap]